# Generate data with specified range under Normal Distribution in Python

Tags: normal-distribution, python, random-generation

This code is used to generate data that ranges from [-10, 10] under the Normal Distribution.

```
x = np.arange(-10, 11)
xU, xL = x + 0.5, x - 0.5 
prob = ss.norm.cdf(xU, scale = 3) - ss.norm.cdf(xL, scale = 3)
```

I understand the xU and xL is the Mean, scale = 3 denotes the Standard deviation. 
I don't understand why does that generating need the subtraction, could someone help me on this?

Answer (score 4):

This code doesn't generate random observations. For each $x\in\{-10,-9,...,10,11\}$, it calculates the following probability:
$$P(x-0.5\leq X\leq x+0.5)=F_X(x+0.5)-F_X(x-0.5)$$